# Check string contains two or more exact words by regex

Tags: php, preg-match, strpos

I have list of words that needs to check is exact available or in string. Also words may be case sensitive.

**For e.g. 1**

`Hello` `world` `how` `are`

**I tried,**

[preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$url      = "Hello world how are you ?";
$haystack = "Hello|world|how|are";
$check    = (preg_match("({$haystack})", $url) === 1);
var_dump($check);
```

**Output**

```
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc1BCsIwEAXQdXuKIbhIwI1rDd16izKkwQFTMsTGUhrPHscIneXn/T9MXGt3G5i477tTTgHaWVB3H0KENaYwAcUVMHnYYoZBXUUSbq8F3fOQpckisohsxpEX0NY0J/8YZ1wcaaX3o/4x6gy/twastXAx0ntjGqc8s/4PSFTrFw)

This example checks like `or` operator.

**For e.g. 2**

[strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
$url      = "Hello world how are you ?";
$check    = (strpos($url, "Hello") >= 0 && strpos($url, "world") && strpos($url, "how") && strpos($url, "are"));
var_dump($check);
```

**Output**

```
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P@f08a@IKOAi5OLU6W0KEcBDGwVlDxSc3LyFcrzi3JSFDLyyxUSi1IVKvNLFeyVrIEqkzNSk7MhKjWKS4oK8os1QLp1oPqUNBXsbBUMFNTUFFBlweYBZTEkgFZgEwbaqqSpCbSxLLEoPqU0t0ADYrWm9f//AA)

This example working but not check exact match try to change first `Hello` word to `hellosssss` it shows always true.

So, any preferable way to check all words exactly and also with case sensitive.

> Note : This example shows only few words but I have many words.

Comment: So you want to get true if all the words on your list are present as whole words in any order in a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes.

Comment: What about split haystack and foreach ?

Comment: `/^(?=.*\bHello\b)(?=.*\bworld\b)(?=.*\bhow\b)(?=.*\bare\b)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried `preg_match("(^(?=.*\Hello\b)(?=.*\world\b)(?=.*\how\b)(?=.*\are\b).+)", $url)` but return `0`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please explain with `PHP` ?

Comment: Of course your code returns 0, you did not use the suggested pattern. You corrupted word boundary constructs. Why escape `a`, `h` or `H`? See https://3v4l.org/o726O

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ohh ! I was forgot `\b` word boundry. Many thanks it is working.